# regex- match exactly one occurrence of @

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match exactly one occurrence of @ in a string. I found that `/^[^@]+@[^@]+$/` working but not `/[^@]+@[^@]+/`

Why should I include the search from beginning to end? Wont the pattern anyway check throughout the string? Can someone explain it for me?

Comment: See [^,$ When to use this symbol in regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22758874/when-to-use-this-symbol-in-regex/22759143#22759143). And to add, the `match` or `exec` methods look for  a match anywhere inside the string, they can return a so called "partial match". What is the problem here, BTW?

Comment: Please add some examples to your question of input and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Without providing `^` and `$`, your RegEx will match parts of your string.

Let's demonstrate with some examples :

> `/^[^@]+@[^@]+$/`

- matches `test@String`.
- doesn't match `test@Str@ing`

> `/[^@]+@[^@]+/`

- matches `test@String`
- matches the part `test@Str` of `test@Str@ing`